# How to add missing values of file on COPY command

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column that comes from a file, although I'm certain that for the other column the value is missing on the file.

Here's the table:

```
create table if not exists user(
    id varchar(36) primary key,
    relevance varchar(3) not null,
    constraint relevance_check check (relevance in ('ONE', 'TWO'))
);
```

The command I want to populated the table with:

```
copy user(id') from '/home/users_ids.txt';
```

The problem is that my column `relevance` is `not null`, and I'd like to set default values on the `relevance` column when copying, but I'm not sure if that's possible.
I cant set a default value on the tables because I need to import data from many files and each one would have a different value on the `relevance` field.

Can I achieve what I want using the copy command or there's another approach for this?

Comment: Why not set the default in the `create table` statement?

Comment: It wont work, I need to copy from other files and I need to set different values for different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the column's default value just for a while, e.g.:

```
alter table "user" alter relevance set default 'ONE';
copy "user"(id) from '/home/users_one.txt';

alter table "user" alter relevance set default 'TWO';
copy "user"(id) from '/home/users_two.txt';

alter table "user" alter relevance drop default;
```

The solution is simple and efficient when you are sure that the import takes place in only one session at a time but is not safe if you intend to use it simultaneously in more than one session. A safer alternative, in this case, could be to use a temporary table, e.g .:

```
create temp table ids(id text);
copy ids(id) from '/home/users_one.txt';
insert into "user"
select id, 'ONE'
from ids;
```

Comment: well, I thought it a bit hacky but worked like a charm. I was expecting that there was another command that I could set along with `COPY` to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a hacky about concurrency. See the updated answer for an alternative.

Comment: Disagree. It is not a bit hacky. It falls under the topic of "validate external data before loading into production tables". It is the only way I ever load data from external files.

Comment: @Belayer - External data can be validated in many other ways. It is not the subject of the question.

Comment: @Belayer, with "a bit hacky" we meant altering the table each time we need to load a different file.